# Export and download files using AngularJS: Error about:blank#blocked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an application using AngularJs and C#, this aplication has a funcionality for export and download a file .xls, but when I click on the button for download the file, the response is "about:blank#blocked" in a new tab of the browser.

HTML Code:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="exportInfo()">
    <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>Export
</button>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$scope.exportInfo = function () {
   if ($route.current.loadedTemplateUrl.indexOf('Index.html') > 0) {

       InfoService.getInfo().then(function (e) {
          $scope.info = angular.fromJson(e.data);
       });
   }
};
```

```
$scope.$watch('info', function (newValue, oldValue) {

    if (newValue != undefined && newValue.length > 0) {

        $scope.sleep = function (time) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) { setTimeout(resolve, time); });
        };

        angular.element("#infoTable").ready(function () {
            $scope.sleep(500).then(function () {

                //code to run here after the delay
                var exportHref = Excel.tableToExcel('#infoTable', 'info');
                window.open(exportHref);
            });
        });
     }
});

app.factory('Excel', function ($window) {

  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><head <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64 = function (s) { return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); },
            format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) };
        return {
            tableToExcel: function (tableId, worksheetName) {
                var table = $(tableId),
                    ctx = { worksheet: worksheetName, table: table.html() },
                    href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                return href;
            }
        };
});
```

Note: this works correctly in Mozilla Firefox browser but not in others browsers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Have you tried adding a preventDefault on the click handler?